# How to prevent this face recognition error?

Tags: face-recognition

whenever i try to run my face recognition program it gives me an error and it is the following:

usage: sample.py [-h] -p PROTOTXT -m MODEL [-c CONFIDENCE]
sample.py: error: the following arguments are required: -p/--prototxt, -m/--model

my program:

[image]

Comment: What's your face recognition program? What's the command you use to invoke it?

Comment: check above i added a picture which is the starting of the programm